# npm install from golang program

Tags: node.js, go, npm

I need to run npm install on folder that I was created

Im doing the following

```
command := exec.Command("../app/node/", "npm", "install")
command.Dir = "."
output, err := command.Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%s", output)
```

**And I get error :**

```
fork/exec ../app/node/: permission denied
```

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: `../app/node/` is a directory, not an executable.

Comment: @JimB - The `/app/node/` is a directory with node program with package.json, how can I do it ?

Comment: Remove the first argument from `exec.Command` and set `command.Dir = "../app/node/"`

Comment: It's also unlikely that the binary would always be located relative to your working directory as `../app/node/npm`. Are you looking to change the working directory of the command, which you can do with the [`Dir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got your arguments to `Command` in the wrong order. [Per the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command), the first argument is the program to be executed (i.e. `npm`), the following arguments are the parameters to pass, in the order that command should receive them, e.g.:

```
command := exec.Command("npm", "install", "../app/node/")
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it now. any idea if I can print the logs from the npm install?

Comment: Yes. There's `CombinedOutput`, `Output`, `StderrPipe`, and `StdoutPipe`, all covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The format for executing a command using `Command` is as follows

`c := exec.Command(<command>,<args>...)`

In your case the command is `npm`.
Therefore the code should be like the following and you can bind `stdout` and `stderr` of the command to shell.So that you can view `npm` logs.

```
command := exec.Command("../app/node/npm","install")
command.Stdout = os.Stdout
command.Stderr = os.Stderr
// Run the command
command.Run()
```